# Upsampling/upscaling a matrix by duplicating rows and columns in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
> m = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I would like to upscale the matrix by simply duplicating each row and column by n. For example, if n is 2, then I would like the result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[2,]    1    1    4    4    7    7
[3,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[4,]    2    2    5    5    8    8
[5,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
[6,]    3    3    6    6    9    9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m[rep(1:3, each = 2), rep(1:3, each = 3)]
```

Or as a general function:

```
upscale_matrix = function(m, factor) m[rep(1:nrow(m), each = factor), rep(1:ncol(m), each = factor)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer D Greenwood's solution but you *could* do:

```
n = 2
apply(apply(m, 1, rep, each = n), 1, rep, each = n)
```